# Sum Field Depends on Group by Month and Year from Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table look like.

tbl_work:

```
ACCOUNT        TOTAL        LAST_UPDATE_DATE
============================================== 
21157         3779444      2018-01-02 00:00:00
21157         7200000      2018-01-04 00:00:00
21157         131275053    2018-02-01 00:00:00
21157         6646465      2018-02-02 00:00:00
21157         36268657     2018-03-01 00:00:00
21157         3622400      2018-03-02 00:00:00
21157         17201657     2018-04-04 00:00:00
21157         3549999      2018-04-07 00:00:00
21157         14364000     2018-05-02 00:00:00
21157         77726800     2018-05-04 00:00:00
```

This will group by the full DateTime, including date, hours and minutes. I wish to make the group by, only by the month and year MM/YYYY and do some SUM to its.

So far I've tried with:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, SUM(total) AS TOTAL, TRUNC(created_date) AS LAST_UPDATE_DATE
FROM rkap_realisasi
WHERE account = '21157' 
AND TRUNC(created_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('1/1/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('1/1/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')
GROUP BY account, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM(TRUNC(created_date)))
```

But it seems didn't work well.

My expected output was:

```
ACCOUNT        TOTAL        LAST_UPDATE_DATE
============================================= 
21157         10979444      2018-01-04 00:00:00
21157         137921518     2018-02-01 00:00:00
21157         39891057      2018-03-02 00:00:00
21157         20751656      2018-04-07 00:00:00
21157         92090800      2018-05-04 00:00:00
```

Any well thought to advise will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I am sure that YEAR_MONTH is not valid input for EXTRACT in oracle. Or if it is, can you please let me know what is the output of this extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by month and year only using following query:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, SUM(total) AS TOTAL, max(created_date) AS LAST_UPDATE_DATE
FROM rkap_realisasi
WHERE account = '21157' 
AND TRUNC(created_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('1/1/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('1/1/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')
GROUP BY account, TRUNC(created_date, 'month')
```

Cheers!!

Comment: How it will ail for 01-01-2019?

Comment: No, excuse me, I stumbled. I had thought using month argument was not enough, but tested, it seems OK(+1).

Answer (score 0):

use max() for date

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, SUM(total) AS TOTAL, max(TRUNC(created_date)) AS LAST_UPDATE_DATE
FROM rkap_realisasi
WHERE account = '21157' 
AND TRUNC(created_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('1/1/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('1/1/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')
GROUP BY account,EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM(TRUNC(created_date)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TO_CHAR()` function with `'YYYYMM'` argument for grouping :

```
SELECT account,
       TO_CHAR(created_date,'YYYYMM'),
       SUM(total) AS TOTAL,
       MAX(TRUNC(created_date)) AS LAST_UPDATE_DATE
  FROM rkap_realisasi
 WHERE account = '21157'
   AND TRUNC(created_date) BETWEEN DATE'2018-01-01' AND DATE'2019-01-01'
 GROUP BY account, TO_CHAR(created_date,'YYYYMM')
```